# Multiple linear regression in R

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, lm

How will I perform multiple linear regression function such as lm in R to fit a prediction rule `ˆy = cx^a_1x^b_2` (where x1 and x2 are attributes, a,b,c are parameters, and ˆy is the predicted label) to my training set consisting of observations `((xi,1,xi,2),yi),i=1,...,n,` with yi all positive?

Answer (score 3):

It's very difficult to read your equation, but if you mean:

y = c × x<sub>1</sub><sup>a</sup> × x<sub>2</sub><sup>b</sup>

then you have (at least) two choices:

1. Use `lm(...)` with the formula: `log(y) ~ log(x1) + log(x2)`. This will generate estimate of the intercept (`log(c)`), and the coefficients of `log(x1)` and `log(x2)` (a and b, respectively). This approach is risky because it relies on the response (`log(y)` in this case) having errors that are normal with constant variance. If the error in `y` is normal with constant variance, then the error in `log(y)` will not be, so you have to carefully examine the residual Q-Q plot to see if that constraint is met.
2. Use your equation directly in a non-linear model,

For example,

```
fit = nls(y ~ c*x1^a*x2^b, data=mydata, start=c(a=1, b=1, c=1))
```

The problem with `nls(...)` is that it may not converge if your initial estimates of a, b, and c (here, 1, 1, and 1) are too far from the best-fit values. Generally I would recommend non-linear regression for this type of problem.